# Функция get_post_meta() не подгружает значения произвольных полей при ajax запросе

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Функция get_post_meta() не подгружает значения произвольных полей при ajax запросе. Код в файле functions.php. Всё остальное работает корректно. Посты подгружаются, все функции отрабатывают. Как можно исправить так, чтобы функция get_post_meta() отрабатывала. При использовании обычной пагинации всё работает.

PHP:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main class="posts">
    <div class="posts__block">
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="header posts__header">Презентації</h3>
            <div class="dots">
                <div class="dot dots__item"></div>
                <div class="dot dots__item"></div>
                <div class="dot dots__item"></div>
                <div class="dot dots__item"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <?php if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                        <div class="post posts__item">
                            <?php
                                $size = 'post-thumbnail';
                                $attr = 'class = post__img';
                                the_post_thumbnail( $size , $attr ); 
                            ?>
                            <div class="post__info">
                                <h4 class="post__header"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'show', true); ?>" class="button button_play post__button">Перейти до перегляду</a>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download', true); ?>" class="button post__button">Завантажити</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
            <?php global $wp_query; ?>
            <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
                <script>
                    var true_posts = '<?php echo serialize($wp_query->query_vars); ?>';
                    var current_page = <?php echo (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>;
                    var max_pages = '<?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>';
                </script>
                <div class="load container">
                    <a href="#" id="load-presentations" class="button load__button">
                        <span class="load__text">Завантажити ще</span>
                        <i class="load__icon fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

javascript:

```
    $('#load-presentations').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var icon = $(this).find('.load__icon');

    icon.addClass('fa-spin');

    var data = {
        'action': 'load-presentations',
        'query': true_posts,
        'page' : current_page
    };

    $.post( myAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        if( response ) { 
            $('.load').before(response);
            current_page++;
            if (current_page == max_pages) $('.load').remove();
        } 
        else {
                $('.load').remove();
            }

        icon.removeClass('fa-spin');
    }); // end post

});
```

Файл functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_load-presentations', 'true_load_presentations');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load-presentations', 'true_load_presentations');

function true_load_presentations(){

$args = unserialize( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ) );
$args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1;
$args['post_status'] = 'publish';

$presentations = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $presentations->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="row">

    <?php while( $presentations->have_posts() ): $presentations->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <div class="post posts__item">
                <?php
                    $size = 'post-thumbnail';
                    $attr = 'class = post__img';
                    the_post_thumbnail( $size , $attr ); 
                ?>
                <div class="post__info">
                    <h4 class="post__header"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo get_post_meta(39, 'show', true); ?>" class="button button_play post__button">Перейти до перегляду</a>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download', true); ?>" class="button post__button">Завантажити</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>

<?php endif;

wp_die();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в true_load_presentations нет строки

```
global $post;
```

В цикле вы используете `the_post()`. Эта функция устанавливает **глобальную** переменную $post. А вы пытаетесь использовать локальную переменную $post.

Comment: Проще заменить $post->ID на get_the_ID()

Comment: Тоже можно. Но насчёт проще - вопрос ). У меня в ответе одна строка, а ваш комментарий предполагает замены в двух строках )))

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.